# Disc brake pistons won't stay in

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, replacement, brake-pads

I'm trying to replace my brake pads but when I try to push one piston in, the other one will come out and when I push it back in the previous one will do the same... how do I fix this so that both pistons remain retracted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to push both pistons at the same time. There are tools for doing this, but many of us use a large flat bladed screwdriver.

You need a steady firm pressure for a few seconds to force the fuild in the lever back into the reservoir. 
Have a look at this [Park Tool video](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/disc-brake-pad-removal-installation) - about 4:10

Answer (score 2):

It turns out there's a lot of air in the brake system, it stopped when I open the lever cap and pull the lever for a few times.

Comment: The hint with the lever cap worked for me. I had the very same issue with two pistons caliper Shimano BR-MT200, One pushed, the other comes out. **The trick for me was to open the lever cap and then push one of the pistons and the other - they are pushed inside the caliper successfully** in that way I lost around 10-15 drops of break fluid _(it was too much)_. Few months ago, I went to a bike service to purge the air from the read brake and filled it to the top. This caused the issue, i had too much break fluid.